# Obfuscating my jar causes a null pointer when executing

Tags: java, obfuscation, proguard

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
        at org.pushingpixels.substance.internal.utils.SubstanceColorUtilities.e(
Unknown Source)
        at org.pushingpixels.substance.internal.utils.SubstanceColorUtilities.z(
Unknown Source)
        at org.pushingpixels.substance.internal.ui.SubstancePanelUI.b(Unknown So
urce)
        at org.pushingpixels.substance.internal.ui.SubstancePanelUI.installDefau
lts(Unknown Source)
        at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicPanelUI.installUI(Unknown Source)
        at org.pushingpixels.substance.internal.ui.SubstancePanelUI.Y(Unknown So
urce)
        at org.pushingpixels.substance.internal.ui.SubstancePanelUI.installUI(Un
known Source)
        at javax.swing.JComponent.setUI(Unknown Source)
        at javax.swing.JPanel.setUI(Unknown Source)
        at javax.swing.JPanel.updateUI(Unknown Source)
        at javax.swing.JPanel.<init>(Unknown Source)
        at javax.swing.JPanel.<init>(Unknown Source)
        at javax.swing.JPanel.<init>(Unknown Source)
        at javax.swing.JRootPane.createGlassPane(Unknown Source)
        at javax.swing.JRootPane.<init>(Unknown Source)
        at javax.swing.JFrame.createRootPane(Unknown Source)
        at javax.swing.JFrame.frameInit(Unknown Source)
        at javax.swing.JFrame.<init>(Unknown Source)
        at aq.S(Unknown Source)
        at aq.<init>(Unknown Source)
        at cg.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventQueue.access$200(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Sour
ce)
```

After obfuscating my client, I now get this null pointer. Does anyone know why I'm getting errors after obfuscating, and any possible solution to avoid such error? The jar works perfectly fine before obfuscation.

Comment: My recommendation is to NOT obfuscate your code.  It just causes problems for everyone, and at the end of the day it doesn't prevent someone from disabling your license checking code anyway.  (And if you are worried about someone "stealing your IP", use a contract and lawyers to protect your rights.)

Answer (score 1):

> Does anyone know why I'm getting errors after obfuscating, ...

Obfuscation changes some things.  For example, if your code base depends on reflection, then obfuscation of class, field or method names could cause reflective operations to fail; e.g. because the actual names not longer match the strings in your code.

Note that the reflection may be happening under the hood in some library you are using.

> ... and any possible solution to avoid such error?

It depends on the actual cause of the problem.  You'll need to debug the obfuscated program to figure that out.

But if the problem is reflection, then one solution is to tell Proguard to not obfuscate the code that needs to be used reflectively.

Comment: This is to do with the frame of the application, it uses the substance library and I have excluded certain classes from being obfuscated that contain the code for setting this frame. Yet still gives me a nullpointer. What can I do to debug this?

Comment: Use a debugger, and debug it like you would any other piece of Java code!  Start by figuring out where the `null` came from.